# How to make a build definition which runs another build definition as one step in VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

So I have 1 default publish build definition and I would like to have another one which is in sync with it and does all the same steps but with an additional step at the end.

Can I have another build definition as one of the steps within another build definition?

This question is for Visual Studio Team Services latest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to run another build in your current build.

#### Option 1: add PowerShell task in your current build definition to [queue another build by REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build)

Assume another build id is 5, so you can add PowerShell task with the script:

```
$body = @{
definition = @{
id = 5    
}
}
$Uri = "http://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body)
```

#### Option 2: install related extension in Market place

There are some extensions you can install for your VSTS account, then you can add the task to queue another build. such as [Queue Build(s) Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jb.queue-build), [Trigger New Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jihedmhadhbi.TriggerNewBuild), [Queue New Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=delegen.DelegenQueueNewBuild) etc.

Comment: How do you get the Invoke-RestMethod to use the OAuth token?  This isn't working for me.

Comment: @TravisEz13 You can also refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483072/how-to-queue-a-new-build-using-vsts-rest-api.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is now enabled without an extension through the UI: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/561