# How to use VSTS Variables in FTP, including Secure Variables

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I need to execute the following script:

```
Param(
   [string]$HostName,
   [string]$UserName,
   [string]$Password,
   [string]$SshHostKeyFingerprint,
   [string]$RemoteFTPFolder,
   [string]$GitUserEmail,
   [string]$GitUserName,
   [string]$PersonalAccessToken,
   [string]$VSTSProjectName
)


try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
   Add-Type -Path  "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = $HostName
        UserName = $UserName
        Password = $Password
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = $SshHostKeyFingerprint
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {

        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Download files
        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

        $transferResult =
            $session.GetFiles($RemoteFTPFolder+"/*", "D:\a\1\s\", $False, $transferOptions)

        # Throw on any error
        $transferResult.Check()

        # Print results
        foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            Write-Host "Download of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
        }

        Set-Location -Path "D:\a\1\s\"

        git config --global user.email $GitUserEmail
        git config --global user.name $GitUserName
        git checkout master
        git pull --rebase origin master
        git add .
        git commit -m "Changes done"       
        git push https://Personal%20Access%20Token:$PersonalAccessToken@mycompany.visualstudio.com/_git/$VSTSProjectName 

    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

I also created the variables, some are clear text, some are like passwords

[image]

However I am getting this error:

```
2018-05-29T14:25:41.4804626Z Error: The value supplied is not valid, or the property is read-only. Change the value, and then try again.
2018-05-29T14:25:41.5591148Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And its not even clear where its failing

Comment: Are you passing the parameters to the script when you run it?

Comment: lol! no, stupid me? how?

Comment: Look at the task where you're specifying the script to run. There should be an "arguments" section.

Comment: yes, but what is the syntax to use variables? https://www.screencast.com/t/cS0iZR2ZLQxg

Comment: Also, please be aware that hard-coding `D:\a\1\s` is extremely likely to break. You should never rely on hard-coded paths, as the agent's working folder is subject to change. In PowerShell, this can be accessed as an environment variable, `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY`

Comment: thanks for that tip, will change it also

Comment: The arguments are passed in the same format you'd pass them on the command line. `-Foo $(WhateverYourVSTSVariableIs)`

Comment: ok, I have a small issue, the password has curly braces in it, and when the variable is replaced, I get this error: Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.. Any idea?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/gjJgD7dIAD

Comment: lol, shame on the menus 1 for a completely valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments to the script something like `-Hostname $HostName`.

You can try using **single quotes** to escape the exception for the password containing Special Characters In PowerShell. (`(` and `{` here).

So, just try to set the value of the `Password` variable something like this : `'b(!d_@{xxx'`

Then try it again.