# How to fix null value build.Definition in TFS Queue Build REST API call

Tags: c#, tfs, build

I am trying to queue a build from my TFS servers using the TFS Rest API nuget package for c#.  However, upon sending the request to the server with the JSON:

```
"definition":{ "id":63 }
```

I get a 400 response back with the error:

```
message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: build.Definition
```

I think I am sending the JSON correctly, considering before I was getting errors saying it couldnt be deserialized, or that there wasnt a JSON in the first place.

Can someone help me figure out what is causing this error and how to fix it?

For reference and showing what I have already used as help:

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

[Queue Build using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483072/how-to-queue-a-new-build-using-vsts-rest-api)

[Again Queueing a build in powershell](https://www.nwcadence.com/blog/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases)

And several other articles (google "queue build tfs rest api c#")

```
//post request for queuing the build
var client = new RestClient(websiteName);
var request = new RestRequest("_apis/build/builds?ignoreWarnings=true&sourceBuildId=63&api-version=4.0", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("{\"definition\"", "{\"id\":63}}");

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalAccessToken))));

request.AddJsonBody(values);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Can you share your all code?

Comment: I can! Give me a minute

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Invoking builds and releases are easier in Powershell if you use [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/1.0.55). Try using the Invoke-APBuild or Invoke-APRelease commands. You can checkout the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/Dejulia489/AzurePipelinesPS) for more details on how to install and setup session data.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to everyone else who has responded.  I will try to tackle this problem again and then see if any of them have worked! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Rest API nuget packages, you can use build-in methods to queue a new build, this will much convenient than using `HttpClient` or other class:

```
var url = new Uri("http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/MyCollection/");
var connection = new VssConnection(url, new VssCredentials());
var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();           
// Get the list of build definitions.
var  definition = buildServer.GetDefinitionAsync("teamprojectname", 33).Result;

//It requires project's GUID, so we're compelled to get GUID by API.
var res = buildServer.QueueBuildAsync(new Build
{
      Definition = new DefinitionReference
{
Id = definition.Id
},
      Project = definition.Project
});
Console.WriteLine($"Queued build with id: {res.Id}");
```

If you still want to use the URL to trigger, here is also an example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.0");
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
request.Method = "Post";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
string json = "{\"definition\":{\"id\":63}}";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.Write(response.StatusCode);
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
     var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thank you so much this looks like exactly what I might have needed! I will try this and if it works I will mark it!

Comment: Is there anyway to get authorization using the VSSCredentials?  I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error.

Comment: In the new `VssCredentials()` check the ctor, you can put username/password.

Comment: Yeah I got it, it was acting weird but leaving it empty again eventually worked.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`"definition":{ "id":63 }` isn't valid JSON.

`{ "definition":{ "id":63 } }` is.

Don't construct JSON as a string, use `ConvertTo-Json` on an associative array to turn an appropriately-shaped object *into* JSON, such as

```
$body = @{
    definition = @{ 
        id = $definitionId
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

Comment: See my problem is, Im doing this in C# and dont know how to convert what you just wrote into what I need. Also thanks for replying on Christmas! Hope you enjoyed your holiday!, Also see my code above to see if I am missing anything.