# execute .exe in azure web job TFS connection authentication error

Tags: tfs, windows-authentication, azure-webjobs, manual

I have created one console app which connect to tfs server using windows authentication. I have upload this app in azure web jobs but while executing it is showing authentication error. How to use my windows authentication on azure web job. I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "PAssword","Domain");

                TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverName), credentials);
                tpc.Authenticate();
```

Comment: What's your TFS version?

Answer (score 0):

For TFS 2015 and above version, to connect to TFS using specific credentials, you could refer below code snippet:

To connect to TFS using specific credentials:

```
// For TFS 2015 & above
// Ultimately you want a VssCredentials instance so... 
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(@"user.name", @"Password1", "DOMAIN");
WindowsCredential winCred = new WindowsCredential(netCred);
VssCredentials vssCred = new VssClientCredentials(winCred);

// Now you can connect to TFS passing Uri and VssCredentials instances as parameters   
Uri tfsUri = new Uri(@"http://tfs:8080/tfs");
var tfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, vssCred);

// Finally, to make sure you are authenticated...
tfsTeamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Besides, you could also choose to use **PAT token**, if you are using TFS2017 and above. 
Especially basic authentication blocked on some repositories or environment .
Just create Personal Access Token (PAT) in the repository. Then use that in your connections to access TFS.

More details please take a look at C.J's answer in this case: [Connect to TFS programmatically from vs 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233619/connect-to-tfs-programmatically-from-vs-2017)