# Create Release Candidate branch automatically

Tags: build, azure-devops, git-branch

I would like to set up our DevOps processes in such a way, so Release Candidate branch would be created automatically every Mon 9AM from Dev branch, and then build/release are triggered afterwards. How can I create Git branch automatically by some schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "built-in" feature to do this, but it is easily scripted out. Once scripted, you can put that script in a Scheduled Build Pipeline. It would consist of a combination of Git commands to create the new branch and a push.

See:

- [Run Git command in a Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Depending on your other Pipeline configurations, they could either trigger automatically based on a wildcard trigger definition (e.g. `release/*`) or you can use the REST API from a script in the Build Pipeline to trigger the builds programmatically.

See:

- [Build Pipeline triggers (wildcard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [Queue a build using the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483269/736079)