# Trigger azure pipeline via webhook?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'd like to trigger an Azure devops pipeline via a webhook.

For example, I'd like to be able to send a POST to some endpoint at Azure with some JSON, then have that endpoint trigger a pipeline to invoke, passing it the JSON.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

This is now available on Azure DevOps Services: [Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-21138#generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml-pipelines)

The request URL will then look something like this:

`https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview`

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else is following along what Anirban Saha suggested, it's worth noting that the placeholder `<Personal-Access-Token>` actually needs to be your username, concatenated with a colon and the actual PAT and that whole thing needs to be base64 encoded, as described in more detail at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat

A slightly easier to use Python example would be:

```py
import json

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=1&api-version=6.0"

PAT_USER = "user@example.com"
PAT = "{personal_access_token}"

resp = requests.post(url, json={}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PAT_USER, PAT))

print(resp.status_code)
print(json.dumps(resp.json(), indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to Queue a Build using a REST API call you can send a POST request to the following URI:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId={definitionId}&api-version=6.0
```

You can get the definition ID by simply opening that particular pipeline in Azure DevOps. THE URL of the page contains the definitionId like this:
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_build?definitionId=1&_a=summary`. For this example, the definitionId is 1. The header of your request should contain a Personal Access Token with scope vso.build_execute

> vso.build_execute - Grants the ability to access build artifacts, including build results, definitions, and requests, and the ability to queue a build, update build properties, and the ability to receive notifications about build events via service hooks.

The following Request in Curl will look like:

```
curl -X POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=1&api-version=6.0 -H "Authorization: Basic <Personal-Access-Token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 0"
```

The following Request in Python will look like:

```py
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=1&api-version=6.0"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic <Personal-Access-Token>"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers["Content-Length"] = "0"


resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

print(resp.status_code)
```

The following Request in Java will look like:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=1&api-version=6.0");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("POST");
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic <Personal-Access-Token>");
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");

System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
http.disconnect();
```

The following Request in C#/ .NET will look like:

```
var url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=1&api-version=6.0";

var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";

httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic <Personal-Access-Token>";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpRequest.Headers["Content-Length"] = "0";


var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

The following Request in Powershell will look like:

```
$Header = @{
"authorization" = "Basic <Personal-Access-Token>"
    }

$Parameters = @{
Method  = "POST"
Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=1&api-version=6.0"
Headers = $Header
ContentType = "application/json"
}
Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. [You can find the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-4.1).

See this answer for more detail: [stackoverflow.com/a/59857117/5225577](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59857117/5225577)

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0`

The required fields are the project, organization and api-version. The optional parameters allow you to customize the nature of the build, such as passing in the source of the build or the check-in ticket.

Comment: keep in mind this isnt a webhook, this is a rest api endpoint protected by auth. I dont think a webhook like experience exists

Comment: thanks, can anyone point to any examples of this? the documentation is horrible. Whats required in the requestBody? whats not etc? I need to trigger a build for a specifc azure-pipeline.yaml in one specific repo in the project. If only "project" is required, what is the result? it would trigger builds for every repo across the entire project?

Comment: See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59857117/5225577

Answer (score 0):

> Trigger azure pipeline via webhook?

I agree with 4c74356b41.

I do not think there is real webbhook support that. AFAIK, Webhook normally don't support `POST` data, it jut a simple `Get`.

You can check the similar thread on the github about this issue for some more details:

[Triggering a build from a webhook](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2366)

Hope this helps.