# Possible to freeze (export) a PR completely once it is closed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

For compliance reasons we would like to completely freeze a PR including the description and all its comments after it got closed. Also a reopening shall be disallowed. In case the branch is continued a new PR shall be created.

Is this somehow possible via certain permissions or do you have any other idea how the complete PR can be freezed (e.g. export the PR data and then use this as frozen snapshot of the PR)?

Thank you

Comment: You could export the data off Azure DevOps by using a service hook event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops  You might also look at the branch policies to see if there is a way to prevent reverts to the branch.  I don't see a way to "reopen" the PR but I show a button to "revert" it, which I think is what you are wanting to prevent.

Comment: It is not so much about changes to the source branch the PR was considering. It is really only about the PR and its comments and findings that should be frozen once the PR was closed. Also ideally reopening the same PR shall be forbidden. But I have the feeling that persisting the PR and its data once it was closed is the best option I have.

Do you know possibly if I can trigger a pipeline via the service hook to persist the PR data?

Comment: I haven't done it but it looks like it's possible:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555358/trigger-azure-pipeline-via-webhook