# does azure devops support dynamic retrieval of value from 3rd party rest API

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-rest-api

Does azure devops support the retrieval of data from rest API and populate that data in the workitem fields

I tried writing powershell script to retrieve data from rest API and populate that data in workitem fields in azure devops

Comment: As per your requirement, you can get the response of 3rd party rest api, and set the value as `field value` in DevOps rest api to update the work item content. In addition, you can run the script in a loop locally, once there's an update, sync to devops work item, or can use devops pipeline to update the work item in schedule. More details in the reply, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the fields of **`workItems`** by calling the API below: -

***GET API: -***

[**Reference1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```http
GET https://dev.azure.com/organization/_apis/work/processes/processId/workItemTypes/witRefName/fields/fieldRefName?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

```
$PAT = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx3ceq"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "7.0"
$processId =  ""
$witRefName = ""
$fieldRefName = ""


$services = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/_apis/work/processes/$processId/workItemTypes/$witRefName/fields/$fieldRefName?api-version=7.1-preview.2" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

$services.value
```

And update the Fields by calling the API below: -

***Update API:-***

[**Reference2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```http
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/organization/_apis/work/processes/processId/workItemTypes/witRefName/fields/fieldRefName?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

```
$personalAccessToken = "YOUR-PAT-GOES-HERE"
$organization = "YOUR-ORGANIZATION-NAME"
$processId = "PROCESS-ID"
$witRefName = "WORK-ITEM-TYPE-REF-NAME"
$fieldRefName = "FIELD-REF-NAME"
$apiVersion = "7.1-preview.2"

$baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/work/processes/$processId/workItemTypes/$witRefName/fields/$fieldRefName?api-version=$apiVersion"

$body = @{
    defaultValue = "Blue"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method PATCH -Headers $headers -Body $body -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Output "Field default value updated successfully."
} 
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
```

There's one more API to update a particular field in WorkItem

[**Reference3**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#update-a-field) :-

```http
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields/{fieldRefName}?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

```
$PAT = "xxxxxxxxxsxq"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"
$ApiVersion = "7.1-preview.3"
$WorkItemId = "123"  # Replace with the actual work item ID

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/_apis/wit/workitems/$WorkItemId?api-version=$ApiVersion"

$body = @(
    @{
        op = "test"
        path = "/rev"
        value = 1
    },
    @{
        op = "add"
        path = "/fields/System.AreaPath"
        value = "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git\\Website"
    },
    @{
        op = "add"
        path = "/fields/System.History"
        value = "Moving to the right area path"
    }
) | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))} -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body
```

Answer (score 0):

After you retrieve the value from 3rd party rest api, you can `parse` the response to get the value wanted, then `set` the value to the `field value` in rest api below to update the work item.

The `$fieldvalue` is gotten from your 3rd party rest api as an example. The reference doc: [Update a field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP#update-a-field).

```
$org = "orgname"
$witId = "workitemid"
$fieldvalue = "Active"     # This is the value got from 3rd party rest api.

$token = "PAT"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/$org/_apis/wit/workitems/$witId" + "?api-version=7.0"
echo $url

$body = @(
  @{
    op = "add"
    path = "/fields/System.State"        # the field path
    value = "$fieldvalue"                # the field value
   }
)

$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PATCH -Headers $head -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body) -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

Please make sure your account (which generated the PAT) has `enough permission` to edit the boards work item, you can simply set the account as `contributor` rule of the DevOps project.
[image]

> does azure devops support dynamic retrieval of value from 3rd party rest API

To `dynamically` retrieve value from 3rd party rest api, you can consider to use DevOps pipeline, and could have options below:

1. You could need to monitor the change of the 3rd party rest api somehow, it depends on your 3rd party rest api, and then [trigger devops pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483269/14996050),  in pipeline you can get the value and update the work item value.
2. Or you can set [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers) on DevOps pipeline, so that the pipeline will automatically run in schedule to update the work item.